# How to get a whitelist of sources used by my application to include in CSP?

Tags: reactjs, security, content-security-policy

I currently have a React app that contacts a Flask API and a few other external entities e.g., Amazon S3. At the moment, I want to improve the application's security and saw that after a recent security scan, I should alter `default-src 'none'`.

I've changed this value in `index.html` to `default-src 'self'` which I can see only allows loading of resources from my own application, however this has caused all styling to be removed e.g., font awesome icons and `react-bootstrap` components. So I was wondering if there's a way to find out all the resources my application uses (only currently in development stage, no deployment yet) and include them in `default-src` as a whitelist.

Comment: There are various CSP-generators online. You could open the network tab in the chrome developer tools to view the requests that are being made. If you forget a resource it will be reported in the browser

Comment: So I can see a few 304 responses for files such as `bundle.js`, `main.chunk.js` but I'm not sure this is the problem. In the console I do get an error saying `Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“default-src”). index.es.js` and `Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“default-src”). injectStylesIntoStyleTag.js
` (multiple lines) which is just a file inside `node_modules`

Comment: Just use Chrome browser, it provides more verbose diag of violations.